# How do I fix my first python code? Name error, class name not defined

Tags: python

I'm in my very first programming class and for whatever reason I CANNOT fix this code. We have to write a program to hold a roster. My teacher has given us a template and I stuck to it exactly. She isn't the best at responding to emails and I have searched the internet over trying to figure it out. I've checked my indentations a million times so I know thats not it. I'll include the entire code below, thanks for helping!

```
class TeamClass(object):
name = ""
jersey = ""
number = ""

def __init__(self, name, jersey, number):
    self.name = name
    self.jersey = jersey
    self.number = number

def set_name(self, name):
    self.name = name

def set_jersey(self, jersey):
    self.jersey = jersey

def set_number(self, number):
    self.number = number

def get_name(self):
    return self.name

def get_jersey(self):
    return self.jersey

def get_number(self):
    return self.number

def display_team_roster(self):
    print("Player")
    print("Name: ", self.name)
    print("Jersey: ", self.jersey)
    print("Phone Number: ", self.number)
    print("-------------")

def menu(self):
    print("")
    print("<<<<<Main Menu>>>>>")
    print("1. Display Team Roster")
    print("2. Add Team Member")
    print("3. Remove Team Member")
    print("4. Edit Team Member")
    print("9. Exit Program")
    selection = int(input("Enter a menu number or 9 to exit: "))
    print("")
    return selection

def display_roster(roster):
    if len(roster) > 0:
        for x in roster.keys():
            roster[x].display_team_roster()
    else:
        print("Roster is empty")

def add_member(roster):
    new_member = input("Enter new member: ")
    new_jersey = input("Enter jersey#: ")
    new_number = input("Enter phone number: ")
    roster[new_member] = TeamClass(new_member, new_jersey, new_number)
    return roster

def del_member(roster):
    del_member = input("Which member would you like to remove?: ")
    if del_member in roster:
        del roster[del_member]
        print(del_member, "has been removed")
    else:
        print(del_member, "was not found")
        return roster

def edit_member(roster):
    existing_member = input("Which member would you like to edit? ")
    if existing_member in roster:
        new_member = input("Enter new members name: ")
        new_jersey = input("Enter new jersey#: ")
        new_number = input("Enter new phone number: ")
        roster[existing_member] = TeamClass(new_member, new_jersey, new_number)
        print(existing_member, "has been changed to", new_member)
    else:
        print(existing_member, "was not found")
        return roster
print("")
roster = {}
menu_selection = menu(object)
while menu_selection != 9:
    if menu_selection == 1:
        display_roster(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 2:
        roster = add_member(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 3:
        roster = del_member(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 4:
        roster = edit_member(roster)
        menu_selection = menu()
print("Exiting program")
```

Comment: Is that how your code is indented? Python uses indentation in place of {} so you'd want to indent the member functions to ensure they were parsed as part of the class definition.

Comment: everything in the class needs to be indented

Answer (score 1):

Python is strict about indenting so in order to make this work correct your class with following indentation:

```
class TeamClass(object):
    name = ""
    jersey = ""
    number = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to 4-space indent all lines below the `class TeamClass(object)` line until the `def menu(self):` line since all of those functions seem to be `TeamClass`'s methods. Although `menu(self)` might seem like a class method since it has `self` in the argument but I don't think that was the case since `menu` was called directly on line `menu_selection = menu(object)`

```
class TeamClass(object):
    name = ""
    jersey = ""
    number = ""

    def __init__(self, name, jersey, number):
        self.name = name
        self.jersey = jersey
        self.number = number

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_jersey(self, jersey):
        self.jersey = jersey

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_jersey(self):
        return self.jersey

    def get_number(self):
        return self.number

    def display_team_roster(self):
        print("Player")
        print("Name: ", self.name)
        print("Jersey: ", self.jersey)
        print("Phone Number: ", self.number)
        print("-------------")

def menu(self):
    print("")
    print("<<<<<Main Menu>>>>>")
    print("1. Display Team Roster")
    print("2. Add Team Member")
    print("3. Remove Team Member")
    print("4. Edit Team Member")
    print("9. Exit Program")
    selection = int(input("Enter a menu number or 9 to exit: "))
    print("")
    return selection

def display_roster(roster):
    if len(roster) > 0:
        for x in roster.keys():
            roster[x].display_team_roster()
    else:
        print("Roster is empty")

def add_member(roster):
    new_member = input("Enter new member: ")
    new_jersey = input("Enter jersey#: ")
    new_number = input("Enter phone number: ")
    roster[new_member] = TeamClass(new_member, new_jersey, new_number)
    return roster

def del_member(roster):
    del_member = input("Which member would you like to remove?: ")
    if del_member in roster:
        del roster[del_member]
        print(del_member, "has been removed")
    else:
        print(del_member, "was not found")
        return roster

def edit_member(roster):
    existing_member = input("Which member would you like to edit? ")
    if existing_member in roster:
        new_member = input("Enter new members name: ")
        new_jersey = input("Enter new jersey#: ")
        new_number = input("Enter new phone number: ")
        roster[existing_member] = TeamClass(new_member, new_jersey, new_number)
        print(existing_member, "has been changed to", new_member)
    else:
        print(existing_member, "was not found")
        return roster

print("")
roster = {}
menu_selection = menu(object)
while menu_selection != 9:
    if menu_selection == 1:
        display_roster(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 2:
        roster = add_member(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 3:
        roster = del_member(roster)
    elif menu_selection == 4:
        roster = edit_member(roster)
        menu_selection = menu()
print("Exiting program")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, I'm trying so hard to understand this but it's just not clicking for me!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a spaces there you need to add spaces in your `name` and `jersey` and `number`

Try This:

```
class TeamClass(object):
    name = ""
    jersey = ""
    number = ""
```